# Problem importing binary registry key into Windows

Tags: binary, registry

I exported a binary (REG_BINARY) registry value from my computer (IE setting). I need to re-import this into another computer (both Windows 7). When I try to import the registry file (same one that I exported), I get this error: "Cannot import file.reg. Not all data was successfully written to the registry. Some keys are open by the system or other processes." I've tried importing in safe mode with to no avail. After some general research, it seems I need to import binary data a special way, but I can't seem to make it work. This is the registry key:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\User Preferences]
"88D7D0879DAB32E14DE5B3A805A34F98AFF34F5977"=hex:01,00,00,00,d0,8c,9d,df,01,15,\
  d1,11,8c,7a,00,c0,4f,c2,97,eb,01,00,00,00,35,9a,4f,4f,a4,58,47,4b,b0,5d,78,\
  59,a6,1d,01,df,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,03,66,00,00,c0,00,00,00,10,00,\
  00,00,60,cf,a0,df,fc,ef,bc,e4,f4,71,a7,e8,ad,4c,3b,5f,00,00,00,00,04,80,00,\
  00,a0,00,00,00,10,00,00,00,80,30,65,dd,2e,3e,2e,45,c0,5b,09,8f,3e,f2,88,79,\
  50,00,00,00,24,c2,46,26,e7,85,28,9a,fd,e0,5f,78,ba,7d,04,c8,34,47,5c,ef,64,\
  bb,7a,be,f8,c4,dd,88,b5,b1,39,c1,19,9b,81,a3,92,ab,7a,70,8f,dd,19,0c,7f,af,\
  66,7d,66,e5,e9,16,6c,20,2b,fa,4a,dd,2b,24,de,df,0a,b2,83,84,29,a7,37,8e,33,\
  b7,56,53,f5,a0,34,0b,8c,42
```

Any ideas how I can import this into another computer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spent some time to sort out this key. It is only accessed when manipulating the search providers in IE. These changes appear to be done under a very protected code path that controls access to this key. This seems reasonable as the search provider is an attack vector that has been exploited by malware/spyware/adware. I am pretty sure you will not be able to manipulate this key directly without running into issues.

- Jason